# RowNumber returning different result after each execution

Tags: t-sql, row-number

Something odd is happening, the Row_Number returns different results after each execution. The results are 1 or 2.

I can't seem to identify the cause for this, does anyone have any ideas?

```
With DUPGASJOB as (
select
[dbo].[RM-JOB].[Job-No]
,loc.[Place-Ref] 
,Address
,Address##2
,place.[Post-Code]
,loc.[Appointment-Area-Code]
,aa.Description
,comp.[Make-Code]
,comp.[Model-Code]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,cycles.[START-DATE],3) CompletedDate
--,CONVERT(VARCHAR,comp.[INSTALLED-DATE],3) InstalledDate
,CONVERT(VARCHAR,instdate.[maxInsDate],3) RecentInstalledDate
,isnull([OC-EMPLOYEE].INITIALS +' '+[OC-EMPLOYEE].SURNAME, 'No Officer') as OperativeName

,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by loc.[PLACE-REF] ORDER BY [MAKE-CODE] desc, instdate.[maxInsDate] asc) AS [Row_Number]

,datediff(DAY, instdate.[maxInsDate], getdate()) NoOfDays
,case when datediff(DAY, instdate.[maxInsDate], getdate()) < 8 then 'Under7Days' else 'Over8Days' end as NoDayCompleted
 from [ih-location] loc
join [co-place] place on place.[PLACE-REF] = loc.[PLACE-REF]
left join [IH_APPOINTMENT-AREA] aa on aa.[APPOINTMENT-AREA-CODE] = loc.[APPOINTMENT-AREA-CODE]  
join [dbo].[RM-LOC-COMPONENT] comp on comp.[PLACE-REF] = loc.[PLACE-REF] and comp.COMPONENT in ('GASBOIL','GASLPG')
AND (comp.[END-DATE] is null or comp.[END-DATE] > GETDATE()) and comp.component in ('GASBOIL','GASLPG')
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[RM-LOC-COMPONENT-CYCLES] cycles ON cycles.[PLACE-REF] = comp.[PLACE-REF]
and cycles.[LIFE-CYCLE] in ('GSOR','GSER') and cycles.[BAR-CODE] = comp.[BAR-CODE]
AND comp.component = cycles.component AND comp.[SUB-LOC-CODE] = cycles.[SUB-LOC-CODE] inner join
[dbo].[RM-JOB] on [RM-JOB].[PLACE-REF] = place.[place-ref] left outer join
[dbo].[OC-EMPLOYEE] on [OC-EMPLOYEE].[CLOCK-NUMBER] = [RM-JOB].[CONTRACTOR-OPERATIVE] 
inner join
(select [PLACE-REF], max([INSTALLED-DATE]) maxInsDate from [dbo].[RM-LOC-COMPONENT] where COMPONENT in ('GASBOIL','GASLPG')
group by [PLACE-REF]) instdate on instdate.[PLACE-REF] = place.[PLACE-REF]
where  [dbo].[RM-JOB].[SOURCE] = '09.SERV' and [SERVICING-JOB] = 1 and [JOB-TYPE] = 'GSER' 
and [dbo].[RM-JOB].[JOB-STATUS-MAP] in ('FINC', 'PRAC') 
)

select * from DUPGASJOB
where DUPGASJOB.[Row_Number] > 0 --  and [PLACE-REF] = '4383'--'5703'--
and NoDayCompleted in ('Under7Days') and 
DUPGASJOB.[Job-No] = '10201102'
order by [PLACE-REF]
```

Any help / thoughts appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't decipher your query/code, but is it possible that the underlying table in your tables is changing between when you query?  I mean, that's probably the most obvious explanation for what you are seeing.

Comment: Does your `order by` condition (`[MAKE-CODE], instdate.[maxInsDate]`) guarantee a unique order or could there be duplicate pairs of values? Aside: Why doesn't `Make-Code` have a table or table alias prefixed?

Comment: @Tim, Once the data is written it won't change.

Comment: @HABO No it didn't and I think that was the cause of the problem. Thanks!